# Is Visual Studio, is there a way to exclude references from Solution Explorer searches?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to find a specific module in a very, very large solution. The problem is, the module is referenced by most assemblies in the solution. Is there a way to exclude the references from the search results in Solution Explorer?

I am using C#.

Example Image:

[image]

Comment: Which language is it, JavaScript?

Comment: If you search for `namespace YourNamespace`?

Comment: I am looking for a particular object in a long list of projects within a solution. The other projects reference the object so I see a lot of references in my results and I'd like to filter out the references.

Comment: Can you add a image of wha you see? I'm no sure, I understand you correctly.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi, Nikolaus! I have taken a snippet of my solution, but doctored the picture so that I'm not disclosing any private information.

Comment: Can you search with a regular expression or some more specific usage with a context which is different than the other references, like a declaration, assignment, function call. Also isn't the module in a respective folder or so?

Comment: Do you need the folder, or classes or something else? Unless you want to add or remove a file, you could search in the code instead of the solution explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

Abcd.ApplicationServer.Common.Utilities.csproj

Answer (score 1):

I know what you mean, because I also have solution with a lot of projects in it and a lot of projects reference one another. My solution (joke intended) to this is more of a workaround, but it works.

First, search for your term in "Search Solution Explorer" field. The results will include references. Then, press "Collapse all" button:

[image: "Collapse all" button location]

The results will now show only parent solution. Finally, click on the search field again, it contains the term you're searching for:

[image]

And press enter. The results list will show a list with highlighted text you're searching for. Unfortunately, it also shows a list of all projects referencing the project you want, but they will be collapsed and the term you're searching for will be highlighted making it much easier to find what you actually want. It will look like this:

[image: Final result]

Obviously, I "photoshopped" the image to not show sensitive data. It's a workaround and I hope Microsoft will add an option to just hide references from the search results list, but it works.